# $y=x^{-a/b}$ for $x<0$

Tags: functions

If you look at the function $y=x^{-a/b}$ for $x<0$, sometimes there exists a positive $y$-value and sometimes there exists a negative. This seems to be determined by the parity of $a$ in the power.

However, what happens as $\frac{a}{b}$ varies continuously over $\frac{a}{b}>0$? An irrational number wouldn't have an $a$ value, so would there exist a $y$-value for $x<0$? Does it go into the complex values?

Comment: You simply cannot define a continuous exponential function with a negative base in the real domain. We can set up a continuous function in the complex domain -- if we are willing to accept that the function is multivalued and choose a branch cut, whose result may not match the value expected from the real domain: $(-8)^{1/3}=1+i\sqrt3$ instead of $-2$.

Comment: Questions about $x^r$ with $x<0$ and $r$ real have been asked & answered many, many times on this website. I encourage you to do a search to find some of the earlier occurrences.